# jQuery show function distorting style of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

So I have an extra div which I show if the appropriate select option is selected. In Firefox works perfectly, but in Chrome or Safari when the extra div is shown, the footer stays where it was before. It does not goes back to the bottom.

Here is an example, try to open it in Safari or Firefox. **The window of the output should be small in height to see what is the problem**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/al_kinkopf/v4po4gwc/7/)

Some code, check the example on Fiddle (check link above)

```
    <style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /* Safari */
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        /* Safari 6.1+ */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .content {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        clear: both;
        min-height: 250px;
        padding: 20px 10%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#extra_div").hide();
    });


    $('.selectpicker').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == '3') {
            $("#extra_div").show();
        } else {
            $("#extra_div").hide();
        }


    })
</script>

<body>
    <div id="okvir_registracije" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;margin-top: 73px; -webkit-flex: 1; -ms-flex: 1; flex: 1;">
        </br>
        <div class="content" id="login_content">
            <form name="registration" class="registration" method="post" id="form_login" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
                <fieldset style="background: white">
                    <label style="margin-left: 10px">Choose one:</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker" name="tip_uporabnika" id="tip_uporabnika" for="tip_uporabnika" onchange="show_div()">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">izberi tip uporabnika</option>
                        <option value="3">Uporabnik</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="extra_div">
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Test 2</label>
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px">Test</label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" name="tip_uporabnika" id="tip_uporabnika" for="tip_uporabnika" onchange="show_div()">
                            <option value="1" selected="selected">izberi tip uporabnika</option>
                            <option value="2">Uporabnik</option>
                            <option value="3">Lastnik</option>
                        </select>
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/></br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/></br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer" style="padding: 15px 0;text-align: center;width: 100%;height:25px;">&copy; Company | info@company.si</div>
</body>
```

Here are two pictures:

Safari:

[image: Safari image]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting height to `100%` will yield a height of the current browser window's size. `Div`'s will size to content by default. Remove all your `height: 100%` constraints, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the height attribute you've given to the body. 
That makes the footer stick to the bottom no matter what.

If you want to have a sticky footer try one of these examples and that should fix your problem.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: But I have a sticky footer..I used flex box to achieve that. And it works perfectly in Firefox.. so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: @ZetaAI: Tijmen is absolutely right. Try unsetting any of the CSS attributes using in Chrome's dev console - disabling body{ height: 100% } clinches it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `display:flex` css rules solves the issue. Not sure what the exact final outcome for the form should be, but it wont overlap the footer when removing the above mentioned rules.

https://jsfiddle.net/v4po4gwc/22/

Comment: I cannot remove display:flex because it ruins the style. I am using flex to have a sticky footer. Anyway, the solution was to remove height 100% (look like).